# Install multiple apps on a Bitnami stack

Tags: installation

I am currently transitioning from my Ubuntu 16..04 LAMP Server to a Bitnami 7.59 Drupalstack. However, I discovered that Bitnami does NOT provide instructions / FAQ on how to install multiple Drupal apps onto a single Bitnami Drupalstack, while "snubbingly" providing an instructional FAQ on how to add multiple Joomla Apps onto a single BitnamiJoomlastack... :0

(*I am using an Ubuntu 16.04 host with Virtualbox5.1 and Ubuntu16.04 guest to run Bitnami drupalstack7.59*)

Therefore, for all you hardcore drupalers I would like to write my own set of docs on how to add multiple Drupal apps onto a single Bitnami Drupalstack.

**One Problem:**

*How* do I actually install multiple Drupal apps onto a Btinami Drupalstack?

I was told by Bitnami Community folks that I should simple exchange "joomla" for "drupal" and [follow this FAQ](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/joomla/#how-to-install-multiple-joomla-applications-in-the-same-instance) which of course did not work.

Along the way, I created my documentation but troubleshooting back-end Bitnami servers is out of my league.

Below are my own configuration notes, derived from attempting follow the bitnami joomla instructions  *(i feel dirty..)*

Can anyone troubleshoot where I am going wrong?

All I get is error code 404 when I try to visit the newly configured Drupal App... `http://127.0.0.1:8080/drupal1/`

My Steps To Create Additional Drupal Apps in Bitnami Drupal7Stack

New Document Root  /opt/bitnami/apps/joomla1/htdocs  translates to /home/username/drupal7stack/apps/drupal/htdocs/

**Rename default drupal app**

1. sudo mv /home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal-site-name] /home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]

**Modify config file located at /home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/conf/httpd-prefix.conf**

2. gedit /home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/conf/httpd-prefix.conf

**FILE CONTENT{truncated}:**

```
Alias /drupal/ "/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/htdocs/"
Alias /drupal "/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/htdocs"
Include "/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

**Modify the `.httpd-app configuration` file at `/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/conf/httpd-app.conf` to use the new path:**

3. **File Content {truncated}:**

   Include "/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/conf/banner.conf"

   Include "/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/conf/htaccess.conf"

**Modify the Apache `.htaccess` file at `/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/drupal1/conf/htaccess.conf` to use the new path:**

4. **File Content {truncated}**

   RewriteBase /drupal1

**Change the name of default db to via phpmyadmin accessible at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/`   (use root login).  Also, create username/pwd of site specific drupal installation**

5. N/A  phpmyadmin GUI

Adjust the settings.php file found at `/home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/htdocs/sites/default/settings.php` to the db specific user created in step five

6. `sudo gedit /home/username/drupal7stack/apps/[drupal1-site-name]/htdocs/sites/default/settings.php`

**restart the drupalstack (apache/mysql), then view new site at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/[drupal1-site-name]`**

7. For drupalstack use `~/drupal7stack$ ./manager-linux-x64.run` , then visit new website

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a direct answer to your question. If it wasn't long I'd post it as a comment.**

Since you mention configuring a server is not your forte, I'd like to recommend you and other Drupal developers at any level of expertise, an alternative development environment to manage multiple instances of Drupal, and other websites in a Vagrant virtual environment:

[Laravel](https://laravel.com/)'s Taylor Otwell also created [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead):

> Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine. No more worrying about messing up your operating system! Vagrant boxes are completely disposable. If something goes wrong, you can destroy and re-create the box in minutes!
>
> Homestead runs on any Windows, Mac, or Linux system, and includes the Nginx web server, PHP 7.2, PHP 7.1, PHP 7.0, PHP 5.6, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Redis, Memcached, Node, and all of the other goodies you need to develop amazing Laravel applications.

It certainly targets the Laravel developers, but I've been using it for most of my local development needs, whether they are Laravel, or Drupal (6, 7 or 8), or any other PHP website.

It makes it much easier to manage any number of websites with different PHP versions, different database needs, and custom hostnames in a single configuration file, to your liking either YAML, or JSON file.

I should mention that I'm not affiliated in any way with Laravel or its creator. I just really like my experience with Homestead so far, and wanted to share.

Go ahead and read its documentation, and install it globally on your machine. Set up a couple websites and give it a try. My guess is you'll have your sites up and running before you can resolve the issues with current Bitnami instance you have.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I minus well check it out.  Hit a bottleneck in my development because trying unsuccessfully to configure postfix to send a frigging email.  You wouldn't happen to know which version of Vagrant works with virtualbox 5.1?  Just got virtualbox stable don't want to reinstall it.